# Is PSPACE vs NEXPTIME known?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity, complexity-classes

I know that P = PSPACE  is a famous open problem, and that EXPTIME = NEXPTIME is also unknown. By the time heirarchy theorem we know that NP is a strict subset of NEXPTIME.

Is anything known about the relationship between PSPACE and NEXPTIME? What about under the assumption that P = NP or that P != NP? Are the containments open problems from PSPACE all the way to NEXPTIME?

Comment: I believe you, but I don't follow your reasoning. P vs NP, and NP vs EXPTIME are both unknown, but P vs EXPTIME is known.

Comment: We know $PSPACE \subseteq EXP $ and we know $EXP \subseteq NEXP $, so we can immediately say $PSPACE \subseteq NEXP$. Since both $EXP$ vs $NEXP$ and $PSPACE$ vs $EXP$ are open questions, we can't say more than that

Comment: @jmite You're right. I blame it being too close to bed time and, therefore, too long since I drank coffee. I believe the correct reasoning is "They're two complexity classes, so the answer to your title question is 'no'." 